# Redirecting Wordpress website with htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

### Situation

Data stored on http://aplhazone.myserver.com.

Domain is http://betazone.com where is probably CNAME record (I don't have access to server configuration).

Here is WordPress with its own htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

### Desired behavior

Redirect all traffic (with 301 probably) from http://aplhazone.myserver.com AND http://www.betazone.com TO http://betazone.com.

### Unsuccessful attempts

### Case one

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.betazone.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^aplhazone.myserver.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://betazone.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

### Case two

```
Redirect 301 / http://betazone.com/

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

### Common errors

**First**

```
The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

    This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
```

**Second**

```
The page isn't redirecting properly Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete. This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies
```

**Third**

```
Charles Error Report
Failed to connect to remote host

Charles failed to connect to the remote host. Check that your Internet connection is ok and that the remote host is accessible. Maybe your network uses a proxy server to access the Internet? You can configure Charles to use an external proxy server in the External Proxy Settings.

The actual exception reported was:

java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Charles Proxy, http://www.charlesproxy.com/
```

---

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It sounds like maybe wordpress is redirecting the request *back* to one of the domains you want to redirect from.

Comment: How can I determine this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^betazone\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://betazone.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Rewrite condition dictates that if the host name doesn't start with betazone.com , redirect to betazone.com . So www.betazone.com and alphazone.myserver.com will get redirected to betazone.com

Comment: I still have this error message: The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

    This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

Comment: That is hinting towards a redirect setup on the www based domain. If you have access to hosting control panel, check it and see if there's a redirection defined there that redirects non-www URL's to www URL's

Comment: There are two relevant CNAMEs in DNS configuration (now I have access). First: * | 7200 | in CNAME | 0 | server.provider.com ||||| Second: www | 7200 | in CNAME | 0 | server.provider.com